# How to run a function when return value is void upon setup in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

So when there is a return value, I can do this in Moq

```
mockStudentRepository.Setup(m => m.Create(It.IsAny<IStudent>())).Returns<IStudent>(s =>
{
    students.Add(s);
    return 1;
});
```

so this lambda gets ran as the mock implementation of the repository.

How do I do this when a method returns void? When I try the same code, Returns is not available. I have something like this right now:

```
mockStudentRepository.Setup(m => m.Update(It.IsAny<IStudent>()));
```

I want to put a lambda that will run when Update is called much like the first code above. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try? Start by testing your code without mocking m.Update

Comment: Sorry, that's entirely my intention, to mock this method. I don't want to run the actual code for it, I just want it to run a fake implementation. What I tried is I created a fake implementation of Student repository, that for sure works, but I wanted to just run a lambda for the method instead of implementing the Student Repository.

Comment: Are you looking for the Callback method? Maybe the [QuickStart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) page has an example that fits your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`Callback`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks) extension.

```
mockStudentRepository
    .Setup(m => m.Update(It.IsAny<IStudent>()))
    .Callback<IStudent>(s => {
        var student = students.Where(x => x.Id == s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if(student != null) {
                //...
        }
    });
```